# How to bundle classes from different modules using maven shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I would like to generate a jar containing package 'com.x' and a class (let's say, Utils.class) from another package 'com.y'. I am able to bundle the complete package com.y in the shaded jar but I only want the one class. It doesn't seem to work with I have below. I have also tried by providing the path to the class: com/bar/cli/pol/Utils.class without any luck.

```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.x</groupId>
         <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.y</groupId>
         <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>shade</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                           <include>com.x:foo</include>
                           <include>com.y:bar:**/Utils.class</include>
                        </includes>
                     </artifactSet>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The question is why would you like to do that cause a shaded package causes sometimes issues?

Comment: It's part of some refactor work but re-consolidating into a shaded jar for compatibility purposes.

Comment: Using shaded jar's as refactor usually cause more issues than it helps..but n nevertheless you should use https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#filters. filters to exclude class cause you are trying to do that in artifactSet which will not work. The artifact is based on [groupId/artifactId/version](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#artifactSet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by doing the following:

```
<configuration>
<finalName>myshadedjar</finalName>
<artifactSet>
    <includes>
        <include>com.x:foo</include>
        <include>com.y:bar</include>
    </includes>
</artifactSet>
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>com.y:bar</artifact>
        <includes>
            <include>com/bar/cli/pol/Utils.class</include>
        </includes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```